# WordPress store locator not working on internet explorer

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress store locator plugin its working fine but when open in internet explorer 11 its not showing anything? I am listing here my website url:

https://www.amberoil.ie/locations/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell your client, that people who uses IE - are to old to have a car anyways - So they have no need for a gas station locator.